# Problem related to the relations between the graphs of unbounded linear operator $A$ and its adjoint $A^*$

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi I  was reading the book "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" by Haim Brezis and I got stuck at the following line. I tried for a long time but couldn't understand how?

The graphs of $A$ and $A^*$ are related by a very simple orthogonality relation:

Consider the isomorphism $I:\mathbb{F}^*\times\mathbb{E}^*\to\mathbb{E}^*\times\mathbb{F}^*$ defined by $$I([v,f])=[-f,v]$$
Let $A:D(A)\subset\mathbb{E}\to\mathbb{F}$ be densely defined unbounded linear operator. Then $$I[G(A^*)]=G(A)^\perp$$

Indeed let $[v,f]\in \mathbb{F}^*\times\mathbb{E}^*$,then
\begin{align*}
[v,f]\in G(A^*)&\Leftrightarrow \langle f,u\rangle=\langle v,Au\rangle\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall u\in D(A)\\
&\Leftrightarrow -\langle f,u\rangle+\langle v,Au\rangle=0\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall u\in D(A)\\
&\Leftrightarrow [-f,v]\in G(A)^\perp---->\textbf{HOW??}
\end{align*}

Here $D(A)$ is domain of $A$ and $G(A)$ is graph of $A$.

I couldn't get how could they get $$[-f,v]\in G(A)^\perp$$

I would be much obliged if any one can help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is explained in [Kato](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kato1.pdf) p. 167-168 .

Answer (score 0):

you need one line to complete that statement
from your last step you have that <(-f,v),(u,Au)>=0
hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

$\langle -f,u\rangle+\langle v,Au\rangle=0\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall u\in D(A)$

says that $[-f,v]$ is orthogonal to all elements of $G(A)$ in the **graph norm**, which is the definition of $G(A)^\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

Before understanding that logical equivalence, you need to know that the dual of a product of normed spaces is the "same" as the product of the duals; formally,

> **Proposition:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, then $(X \times Y)^*
>  \cong X^*\times Y^*$ by the isomorphism $g \mapsto (g_{|_{E \times 0}}, g_{|_{0 \times F}})$. (the norm on $X \times Y$ induces naturally the norm on $X^*\times Y^*$)

Now, how does $G(A)^\perp$ look in $X^*\times Y^*$?

$$G(A)^\perp = \{ g \in (X \times Y)^* : \forall (x,y) \in G(A), g(x,y)=0 \}
=\{(h,k) \in X^*\times Y^*: \forall (x,y) \in G(A), h(x)+k(y)=0 \}=\{(h,k) \in X^*\times Y^*: \forall x \in D(A), h(x)+k(A(y))=0 \}.$$

From this equality, the equivalence you want to prove is immediate.